# How to make something editable by everybody while keeping track of history?

Tags: django, django-1.7

I want to add some wiki like feature to my already existing project.

The only reasonable example I found suggested to just add a "is_published" boolean field and have multiple versions with the same slug where only one version of each slug is ever published.

Now I find some trouble with that idea, because I need slug and ID to be unique and unchanging for every object, because I use those attributes in the url.

So I thought about doing something like this.

Imagine I have a model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
  slug = models.SlugField()
  subject = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  body = models.TextField()
```

Now to get my feature I try this:

```
class Post(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
  slug = models.SlugField()
  cv = models.ForeignKey('myapp.Version') // current version

class Version(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User') // this is the editor
  subject = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  body = models.TextField()
  post = models.ForeignKey('myapp.Post', related_name="all_versions")
```

This would allow me to use the Post object like before with minimal changes. I only need to add "cv" when I want to access subject or body. It shouldn't use additional resources when used with select_related.

Is there a better way to do this?

Is there even a way that removes the need of inserting "cv" ?

Answer (score 1):

There is an easy way to do it but you'll have to drop the uniqueness of the SlugField.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=False)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    body = models.TextField()
    version = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=True)
```

What you do in your view is simply pull the instances with the same slug and order them by date, the latest date will obviously be the current version.

Then in your template, you'll use the id field as a get variable, the redirect url for a version should look like this:
`http://someurl.com/this-unique-post?v=3`

Where 3 is the id of that post's version, then if you want to make, say the version with id=3 as the current version, you'll just save/update it again!

Hope this helps!

Comment: I thought about this way, but there are a few problems I can't seem to fix. How can I have the ID stay the same? As I said I have it in the url so it can't change. Also how do I effectively pull for a list view?

Comment: As for keeping the id the same across multiple entries, i'm afraid you can't, an id is an id after all, but you can add another field parent_id that will hold the id of the original entry, so that each time a user makes changes, a new Post entry is created with a parent_id field that refers to the original entry's id, and simply use that field in your views.

Comment: And how would I query for a list view? Because I'd need to get the latest version for a bunch of different Posts. I don't see how this could be done in a single query.

Answer (score 0):

There are django apps for that. for example: https://github.com/etianen/django-reversion